# subrings and ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_4[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Find, with proof, all the subrings and ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_4[i].$

The subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_4[i]$ that I could find are:

$\{0\}, \{0,2\}, \{0,2i\}, \{0,2+2i\}, \{0,1,2,3\}, \{0,2,2i, 2+2i\}, \{0,2,1+i, 3+i, 2i, 2+2i, 1+3i, 3+3i\}, \mathbb{Z}_4[i]$.

The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_4[i]$ that I found are:
$\{0\}, \langle 2 + 2i\rangle = \{0, 2+2i\}, \langle 2\rangle = \{0,2,2i, 2+2i\},\langle 1\rangle =\mathbb{Z}_4[i],$ but I'm not sure if this is all of them.

> I think I'm missing some ideals and subrings; I was wondering if there's some sort of algorithm-like approach I could use to find these subrings and ideals more easily? If so, then could this algorithmic approach be used to find all the subrings and ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_6[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$? For $\mathbb{Z}_3[i],$ some subrings would be $\{0\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \mathbb{Z}_3[i],\cdots$ and some ideals would be $\{0\}, \mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ (in fact $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ is a field so these are the only ideals).

Answer (score 1):

Factorize $n=\prod_j a_j^{e_j}$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ where the $a_j$ are irreducibles, the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(n)$ are $(\prod_j a_j^{d_j}),0\le d_j\le e_j$.

$4 = (1+i)^4$.

Enumerating the subrings seems harder.